# java right triangle angles

Tags: java, geometry, angle

Ok, I am supposed to calculate the angle of a right triangle using Java. The measurements of the sides are a = 3 and b = 4 with the hypotenuse being c = 5. If I use Math.sin, it does not calculate the angle created by a and c. Is there another Math function I am not aware of? I have spent a long time trying to figure this out to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First calculate the angle by hand (with a scientific calculator). If you don't know how, you should ask a question on our sister site [Math.SE].

Comment: It is NOT 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The probably source of the problem is that sin works in radians, rather than degrees.

Answer (score 0):

To find the angle bounded by the side a and the side c, try using `Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((double)a/c))`. The passed value d to `Math.acos(d)` will have to be `double`.`'Math.acos(d)'` will give the arc cos in radian. Go through [Math documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Comment: It depends on exactly which angle he wants, which isn't clear.  If "the angle created by a and c" means "the angle bounded by the **side** _a_ and the **side** _c_", then I think he needs `acos`, not `asin`.  But the wording isn't clear.

Comment: Yes, I meant I need to find the angle created by a and c.

Comment: @ajb Actually my intention was to respond for the question:
**_If I use Math.sin, it does not calculate the angle created by a and c. Is there another Math function I am not aware of?_** 

so to create angle we use **Math.asin(d)** instead of **Math.sin(d)**. His wording wasn't clear to me either.

Comment: See, I thought asin was used to find the length of the arc created by the angle and radius. If asin is used to find the angle, what is used to find the arc?

Comment: it is ok. We caught your drift.:)